# How we can update the permissions of a file using google drive api with PHP?

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I want to update my user permissions using google drive api with PHP.
I am doing like this-

```
        $Service = new Google_Service_Drive($Client);

        $OptParams = array(
            'fields' => '*'
            );
            $Reponse = $Service->files->get($FileId,$OptParams);

            foreach ($Reponse->getPermissions() as $PermissionValue) {
                $PermissionId = $PermissionValue->getId();
                $PermissionValue->setRole('reader');
                $result = $Service->permissions->update($FileId,$PermissionId,$PermissionValue);
            }
            return $result;
```

From the above code I can get my file id and permission id both but its throwing me error on update method. What am I doing while updating the user permissions for a file.

I am getting this error-

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Service\Exception: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "fieldNotWritable", "message": "The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable." } ], "code": 403, "message": "The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable." } }
```

Can anybody tell me What am I doing wrong or what am I missing? What is the correct way of updating the permissions for user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

You are providing all properties in [Permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions) returned by [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get). Some of these properties, like `id` itself, are not writable.

#### Solution:

[Permissions: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/update) uses patch semantics to update the permission, which means only the fields you directly provide will get updated; there's no need to provide fields like `id`, since not providing them doesn't cause these to get removed from the updated permission.

Therefore, you should only provide the fields you want to update. In this case, that's `role`. Create a new permission object (see [Google_Service_Drive_Permission](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Drive_Permission.html)) and set its role:

```
foreach ($Response->getPermissions() as $PermissionValue) {
    $PermissionId = $PermissionValue->getId();
    $updatedPerm = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
    $updatedPerm->setRole("reader");
    $result = $Service->permissions->update($FileId,$PermissionId,$updatedPerm);
}
```

#### Note:

This will fail for the permission related to the file owner, since you cannot remove the owner of a file without transfering ownership (see parameter `transferOwnership` in the method documentation).

Comment: @lamblichus, Thankyou so much for your help, It did worked and Yes I have also handle the owner part issue.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [permissions get method](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/get) returns a [Permissions response](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions#resource) object. This object contains a number of fields which are not writeable.

The [permissions update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/update) method uses HTTP Patch methodology.  This means that it is going to try and update every property that you send even the ones that are not writeable.

So by loading $PermissionValue object from the get permissions method you are populating to many propertyes.

You should create a new permissions object and only set what you need to update. in this case the role.

```
$newPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
$newPermission ->setRole('reader');
$result = $Service->permissions->update($FileId,$PermissionId,$newPermission );
```